# VBA Loop to MkDir from a SQL query

Tags: sql, vba, loops, ms-access

I am trying to get a VBA function to create a folder for each program in a table. The table, TPrograms, has ProgramID as the key field. As far as I can tell, it's not actualy reading the table.

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM TPrograms")
Do Until rs.EOF = True
    If Len(Dir("Y:\Education\TEST\" & ProgramID, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
       MkDir "Y:\Education\TEST\" & ProgramID
    End If
    rs.MoveNext
Loop

MsgBox "Finished looping through records on record " & ProgramID
```

It runs, but it does nothing and ends with "through records on record" with no number at the end. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: With `Option Explicit` in the module's Declarations, Access will notify you that `ProgramID` is problematic.  You know it's meant to be the name of a field in the recordset, but Access doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

You are actually not setting the variable `ProgramID`. Assign it a value with:

```vb
ProgramID = rs!ProgramID
```

Together:

```vb
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM TPrograms")
Do Until rs.EOF
    ProgramID = rs!ProgramID
    If Len(Dir("Y:\Education\TEST\" & ProgramID, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
       MkDir "Y:\Education\TEST\" & ProgramID
    End If
    rs.MoveNext
Loop

MsgBox "Finished looping through records on record " & ProgramID
```

Of course you can also use the field from the recordset directly

```vb
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM TPrograms")
Do Until rs.EOF
    If Len(Dir("Y:\Education\TEST\" & rs!ProgramID, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
       MkDir "Y:\Education\TEST\" & rs!ProgramID
    End If
    rs.MoveNext
Loop

MsgBox "Finished looping through records on record " & rs!ProgramID
```

I suspect that you don't have an `Option Explicit` at the top of your module and didn't therefore notice that the variable `ProgramID` was not declared. Always use [`Option Explicit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-explicit-statement), this helps much in avoiding errors.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly the problem! I'm at the bleeding edge of what I know and on a deadline, and I really appreciate the help.
So making sure I understand this: The SQL statement pulled that table into a recordset, but the IF statement couldn't yet use it because I had to separately define a variable. So the first one defines the variable first and then runs the statement, the second one pulls the variable directly out of the recordset as part of the action.

Comment: Because you didn't have `Option Explicit` at the top of your code, you were able to use variables never declared. Therefore, you did not notice that `ProgramID` was a non-declared and not assigned variable instead of being the field from the RecordSet. The RecordSet `rs` has indeed loaded the whole table, but you never used its results with `rs!ProgramID`. Whether you use the key directly via `rs!ProgramID` or assign it first to a variable makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

You're not assigning the VBA variable 'ProgramID' a value. You can use the .fields property of the recordset to get the value of a column for the current row.

```
Do Until rs.EOF = True
    ProgramID = rs.Fields("ProgramID").Value

    If Len(Dir("Y:\Education\TEST\" & ProgramID, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
       MkDir "Y:\Education\TEST\" & ProgramID
    End If
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```